# Find Cell Without #N/D

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a problem with a Google Sheets formula. 
 I am looking for a formula to solve this problem.
On [the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HtjR.png) I have a list where I can enter items.
Once the item is selected, the right side looks for me in which row of a column I have saved that item, I'm looking for a formula that gives me the value of the cell in which there is no #N/D 
 For example in the line 16 i want the cell with ?? that it value is 337, in the second line a cell with 244 etc 
It's possibile or it's better with a script of google app script?

Comment: Sorry google sheet, now change the tag

Comment: Please share a link to your spreadsheet (or to a copy of your spreadsheet) so that the volunteer contributors here have your data and layout to test solutions. In addition to having access to the data and layout, there are many other factors to consider, such as data types, international location, etc. Help us to help you: share a link.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I know that the data is only numeric and that only one cell has a value, for this reason I can solve it in a simple way like this:
`=SUMIF(K16:Q16;"<>#N/A")`

Comment: If you are happy with your solution, great. There are ways to get all results for all rows with a single formula. But as I commented above, you'd need to provide a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).